# Difference between direct invocation of assembler and invocation of compiler with option -c

Tags: gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler

I have some .s assembly codes to assemble in C. I would like to have .o object files. I found two ways to get the .o files.

The first one is to use the compiler and stop after assembling (with -c option):

```
.\HightecInstall\bin\ppc-vle-gcc -Wa,--gdwarf-2 -DDEFAULT -fno-inline -c -o sample.o sample.s
```

The second is to direct invoke the assembler:

```
.\HightecInstall\bin\ppc-vle-as --gdwarf-2 -DDEFAULT -fno-inline -o sample.o sample.s
```

Due to direct invocation of the assembler, I think "-Wa" is not necessary. But the second does not work. It gave me errors like "unrecognized option -EFAULT".

Does anyone know the difference between the direct invocation of the assembler -as and the use of compiler with -c option if I want to convert .s file to .o file? Thanks.

Bo

Comment: I think with calling gas directly, you don't have a C preprocessor step....

Comment: Pass `-v` switch to `gcc` then you will see how it invokes the various tools. You can drop `-DDEFAULT` as that has no effect in either case (since lower case `.s`  files are not preprocessed) and `-fno-inline` makes no sense for assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Raw assembler is a very primitive tool so it does not support normal GCC flags (`-D`, `-f`, etc.). It's command-line syntax also changes on different platforms so it's normally recommended to use `gcc` to assemble `.s` files (similarly to how we normally use `gcc` to link instead of calling `ld` directly).

Comment: `-g` is an assembler option for the GNU assembler as well, and has a similar effect of creating more metadata for debugging: it makes debug info for each asm source line, the same way that compilers would for each C source line.  But yes, there's no CPP so `-D` is meaningless.  (Actually, it's silently ignored by the GNU assembler as a non-option argument, explaining the error message.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/as.1.html)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, I figured that out as well but forgot to update the answer. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

`-D` is silently ignored by the GNU assembler as a non-option argument

> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/as.1.html
>
> `-D`  Ignored.  This option is accepted for script compatibility with
>              calls to other assemblers.

So `-DDEFAULT` is parsed basically the same as `-D -D -EFAULT`.  There's no -E or -EF option, so you get that error message.

---

Even with gcc, your file has a `.s` suffix (not `.S`), so gcc won't run it through the C preprocessor.  So `-DDEFAULT` has no effect.  Neither does a C-to-asm code-gen option like `-fno-inline`.

`-gdwarf-2` has a similar effect for GAS directly or for invoking it via gcc.  But when passed to the assembler, it makes debug info for source-level debugging *of the asm*.  i.e. source line info for each asm source line, mapping to/from machine-code addresses.

I'm not sure what happens when running the assembler via gcc.  Assembler directives for emitting debug info will already be present in the `.s` if you got it from a C compiler that you ran with `-g`.